# Input key in dd/mm/yyyy format in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

How to enter a date using dd/mm/yyyy?

For example - I want 25th September, 2022 to be entered in a column, so I have type `09-25`. But in Excel, it's possible if I type only `25-09`.

Is there any way to change input of the date?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Set **File > Settings > Locale** to a locale that matches your preferred date format.

Comment: Yes, that worked, but it changes my language too. I want to keep the language as English only.

Comment: As asked in the question, I got the answer but then it changes the language in the sheet. For me, it changed to Hindi Language, when I type a date `09-09-22` (Sept 9, 2022), it's written in Hindi as `सित॰ 9, 2022`.

Comment: I have changed to a preferred locale, but I want only for preferred not language. When I am changing the locale, both are getting changed.

Comment: Changing the spreadsheet locale does not change the user interface language in menus, dialog boxes and the like. It only affects the formatting of dates, numbers, currencies, formulas and text direction. If you do not want Hindi month names, choose another locale that (1) has the date format you want, and also (2) has month names in the language you want. Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/166823/edit) your question to clarify what you are trying to do.